# How to make android app more faster in connecting to the remote servers

Tags: android

I am building an android application that communicates to a remote server, this fetches data from the remote server database as well as transfer information from the android app to the server database.  I actually establish the connection between the remote server and the android app using the httpClient with json, php and mysql functions.

This idea works very well, buh after testing the system for some time,  I realised the app takes a bit longer in connecting to the server although I use the `async task`  class to work on the background and also use a very fast internet access.

The main aim, is to make the application very fast in connecting to the remote servers.

**MY QUESTION**

Is there a better way I can make the application establish or faster in connecting to the remote servers. I would be very grateful for any idea or better still links to read more about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the volley library.
one more qtn - r u using deprecated api? I think **httpClient** is deprecated in android..

Comment: Your question is completely open ended. To answer that we need to know where your app is taking the time, and exactly how long it is since it may be perfectly reasonable as-is. I'd suggest timing each of the critical parts of the code (going to the network, interacting with the DB, etc) separately and provide that information.

Comment: I can't see any problem on your client side (android). Check your network response times and your server load, to know where is the problem (connection/read)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Volley library. It is very fast for accessing the data from server developed by google team.
Their are some example you can see in below links.
visit:
Click [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Comment: Volley uses the same communications methods as any other HTTP communication. If anything it's going to be slower as it has layers of abstraction on top of them. volley isn't meant to be fast, it's meant to facilitate ease of coding.